# How to access values from an array of hashes - Ranking poker hands in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, poker

```
@hands = [

  [{"suit": "heart", "value": 5},{"suit": "heart", "value": 8},{"suit": "spade", "value": 1},{"suit": "club", "value": 5},{"suit": "diamond", "value": 5}],
  [{"suit": "club", "value": 1},{"suit": "club", "value": 3},{"suit": "club", "value": 8},{"suit": "club", "value": 9},{"suit": "club", "value": 11}],
  [{"suit": "diamond", "value": 2},{"suit": "heart", "value": 2},{"suit": "spade", "value": 2},{"suit": "club", "value": 6},{"suit": "diamond", "value": 12}],
  [{"suit": "club", "value": 2},{"suit": "heart", "value": 3},{"suit": "spade", "value": 5},{"suit": "club", "value": 4},{"suit": "diamond", "value": 1}]
]

def get_hands
  @hands.each do |hand|
    hand.each do |card|
      print "#{card.fetch(:suit).chars[0]}" + "#{card.fetch(:value)}"
    end
  end
end
```

Output of `get_hands` is:

```
h5h8s1c5d5c1c3c8c9c11d2h2s2c6d12c2h3s5c4d1
```

Is there any way? that I can save the values from each hash `hand` so that I can push the `5` cards from each `hand` into their own variable. eg: `Hand1`, `Hand2` etc?

I am a Ruby beginner and have been going round and round for few hours, now trying different things to get to even this point. I am just getting confused with my thought process from going round in circles.

Comment: Sure. Make `hand1` and Array or Set, where each element is a card.

Comment: Why would you need `hand1`, `hand2`, ... hardcoded variables? You can always refer to the i-th "hand" in you array via `@hands[i]` instead. Also, it is not clear what do you mean by "save values from each hash hand" - could you please what is the desired output? Is it what `get_hands` does now and you only want it to be done separately for each hand?